# Laravel Relationship: A division has many ranks, a rank has 1 division, and a user has only 1 rank

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship, laravel-7, eloquent-relationship

For instance:

**Divisions:**

- Division A
- Division B
- Division C
- etc...

**Ranks in Divisions**

- Division A
  -- Rank 1, Rank 2, Rank 3, ...
- Division B
  -- Rank a, Rank b, Rank c, ...
- etc..

And a user would only be assigned a rank. For instance, they would be "Rank 1".

Exactly what type of relationship would this scenario require? And how would the tables setup have to look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `division` table would be

```
id | name
```

Your `rank` table would be

```
id | division_id | name
```

your `user` table would be

```
id | name
```

your `user_rank` table would be

```
id | user_id | rank_id
```

As per relationship in Laravel

**Division** Model

```
class Division extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'divisions';
    public function ranks()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Rank','rank_id','id');
    }
}
```

**Rank** Model

```
class Rank extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'ranks';
    public function divison()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Divison','rank_id','id');
    }
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User',''user_rank','rank_id','user_id');
    }
}
```

**User** Model

```
class User extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'users';
   
    public function ranks()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Rank',''user_rank','user_id','rank_id');
    }
}
```

Comment: If a rank can be assigned to multiple users, would it not be necessary to instead use $this->hasMany(User::class, 'user_id', 'id') and have a rank() function in the Users Model as well? I'm still grasping onto Laravel, so pardon me.

Comment: @Brennan if a user can have only one rank, as indicated in the question, it should be hasOne instead of hasMany. But yes, you are right about having the rank relationship in user model

Comment: @user3532758 Ah okay, so what I'm getting at is that this answer is correct (it does seem logical to me, at least), though what's missing is essentially is this function in the User model: public function rank() { return $this->hasOne('App\Rank', 'rank_id', 'id'); }

Comment: User has Many rank then it would be belogsToMany relation please check my edited answer.

Comment: I have edited the answer as per your requirement, if users have many ranks then it should be belongsTomany. If user have only one rank then it should be `hasone,belongsTo`.